# Gpu rig, possibilities

Tags: gpu, cryptography

My plan is to buy old and cheap graphic cards on the internet and build a gpu rig for password cracking.

I have been playing around for some while with OpenMPI and I love the fact that its possible to have multiple gpus working together on the same job.
My problem is that I only have 1 old cheapy graphic card which is slower then the cpu itself.
I still having problems getting it all to work properly.

Before I go out and spend lots of money for something that aint working (done it before :-/) I thought by myself.. Lets ask more experienced people first.

So here is my question,

Is it possible to build a gpu rig with different cards working together to crack passwords?

I sure hope someone knows to answer or even better, have done this him- herself

P.s

Im sorry if this question is in the wrong forum but I could not figure out which aspect it belongs to.. Hardware, linux, software, etc

Comment: It depends heavily on how the passwords are hashed. GPUs help with some algorithms, not with others. I'm not sure if old GPUs will be ever better than a recent CPU though.

Comment: I dont need to know if its better (not right now). I only want to know if this is possible?